# Installing a local npm package in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have a local package that I packed into an npm package using `npm pack`.
I then install this package to some nodejs apps that are external to this local package using `npm install path/to/package.tgz`. This works like a charm, but now I want to dockerize the apps and I can't manage to install the local package.

My structure looks like this:

```
-my_package
 |-package.tgz

-app1
 |-app1.js
 |-Dockerfile

-app2
 |-app2.js
 |-Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

# Copy and download dependencies
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy the source files into the image
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4002

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And the error I'm getting when running `docker build . -t js/app1` is:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @my_package@file:/package.tgz (sha512-u9tY/j1VOzO1y1RpcCgYteDOEsh7TaSMYwmR2Rs7hoJopE11qa1XcnrrMKNx1/H/aHsZ3Gr0bOMx1SygYTf/rg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @my_package@file:/package.tgz (sha512-u9tY/j1VOzO1y1RpcCgYteDOEsh7TaSMYwmR2Rs7hoJopE11qa1XcnrrMKNx1/H/aHsZ3Gr0bOMx1SygYTf/rg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 9.2.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.2.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.2.0` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /my_package/package.tgz
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/my_package/package.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-09T04_54_04_868Z-debug-0.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm ci' returned a non-zero code: 254
```

Some times I get `null` instead of the `sha512` stuff, otherwise the error is the same.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: try add `COPY ./my_package/package.tgz /my_package/package.tgz` before `RUN npm install`

Comment: can you tell us your dockerfile path relative to ./my_package directory?

Comment: @AliHassan Dockerfile would be at `/home/js/projects/app1/Dockerfile` and package at `home/js/projects/my_package/package.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) says:

> COPY obeys the following rules:
>
> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot
> COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build
> is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
> daemon.

The easiest fix is to paste the file(s) you need into the same folder that your Dockerfile is in.